Modifying the Laravel response HTML causes unit tests to fail
Running on Laravel 10, with PHPUnit 10.5.38, I have a middleware that adds the environment to the <title> tag so stakeholders are more aware of when they are on Dev or UAT environments.
<title>My Page</title> becomes <title>DEV - My Page</title>
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
{
    $response = $next($request);

    $isHtmlResponse = $response->headers->get('Content-Type') === 'text/html; charset=UTF-8';

    if (!app()->isProduction() && $isHtmlResponse) {

        $content = $response->getContent();

        $content = preg_replace(
            '/<title>/i',
            '<title>' . strtoupper(config('app.env')) . ' - ',
            $content
        );

        $response->setContent($content);
    }

    return $response;
}

When I run unit tests with assertions against a view, the following error occurs:

The response is not a view.

Example test:
public function test_why_it_is_not_a_view(): void
{
    $this
        ->get(route('my.login'))
        ->assertViewHas('x', 'y')
        ->assertOk();
}

This test should fail. There's no x property with value y. The same happens on what should be passing tests.
When I exclude the middleware completely, things work. When I add logic to exclude the regex with app()->runningUnitTests(), things work.
So, what is it about $response->setContent($content) that causes upset?

Middleware doesn't seem to be the right place for adding "DEV" to the title. Why isn't this logic in a blade template?

@NoOorZ24 - Thanks for the reply. It's an app with multiple frontends and this was the easiest route to take. I may go with your suggestion but I'd still like to know what causes the test to fail.

have you used the ->assertSee(); ?
